# ssas dimension processing key not found error

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, business-intelligence, dimension

I have this strange case where I am trying to process a dimension, the data source is MSSQL
and when I try to process this dimension I am getting this error

> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'application', Column: 'Full_Name', Value: 'Mr Peter McDonald'. The attribute is 'Applicant Full Name'.

Since I *think* I know what the problem is, I have set the case sensitive property for this column and I tried processing again and it's giving me the same result.

when I query for the column using like, I get two records

> Peter McDonald
>
> Peter Mcdonald

I would normally assume that setting the case sentivity would solve the problem, but it's not working in  this case, so I was wondering if anyone knows how to resolve this.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

Comment: I don't know if that is the case but the value is  'Mr Peter McDonald' and your query returns Peter McDonald. If it was a case of multiple keys the error would say so

Comment: Sorry I am not sure if I am understanding your comment correctly, are you referring to the difference of having and not having quote?

Comment: oh that part, yeah sorry I missed that when I copy pasted the value, both of them have Mr

Comment: I would suggest to you to do the following then. Make a named query on the table you use as the dimension-table, and add a new incremental key column to use as a key for dimension.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your schema?

Comment: Why would needing a new key value for the dimension give the error he got "attribute key cannot found"

Comment: I had the same error message, except for object names and key value. I found a few similar posted questions, but no answer that made sense to me. I didn't have a duplicate value in the attribute key. The error referenced not the dimension but the referencing fact table. This post solved my problem.

[Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Even though key Exist in Dim Table..][1]


  [1]: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1219713-17-1.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry guys for getting back too late. 
I haven't logged into stackoverflow for a long time.

The short version :
This is basically caused by SQL server is not case sensitive for comparison by default.
So if you want to prevent this problem you have to make the table or the database case sensitive - set  collation to ASCS

Slightly longer version :
Even though MSSQL matches Case insensitive what it still stores values differently, and this becomes an issue for SSAS when it tries to do a distinct on a particular column.
It's been a while so I can't remember exactly but it will have two values for 1 index and it will complain like the question I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

you need to re-deploy your cube after you change the case-sensitive settings.

Comment: I do this all the time, and I didn't do the job. Thanks for your comment though.